Scanning for BLE advertising extension long range
I have never been able to scan for long range advertising extensions with Android. Have you managed this ever ?
Rumour has it this is fixed now in Android 15, as this wasn't connected up in Android correctly.
I have not found any documentation and hence the question.
Regards Paul

This might be an issue of your phone https://github.com/NordicSemiconductor/Android-BLE-Library/issues/166
